# Android app only accepts self signed certificates on first start

Tags: android, https, self-signed

I have this very annoying problem, that when I start my app the first time, my self signed certificate is accepted. When I close the app and start it again, the certificate is not accepted any more. What am I doing wrong?

This is a debug build so I have no clue why it would only fail on the second start.

EDIT 1:

It is a Cordova application that requests a resource via https. I just found this article http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cordova-dev/201401.mbox/%3C0AC46520-9B83-4934-8E4B-BCEAC44F2DFE@devgeeks.org%3E but it doesn't really say how to fix the issue.

The HTTP error code I get is status 0, which means, that the certificate is invalid/not accepted.

EDIT 2:

I recently discovered that this is an issue with Android 4.4 in general. Any ideas what could be different in 4.4 that causes this problem?

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to work with. Please post sample code showing the problem, (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a description of the desired and actual behaviors, and any error logs.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can solve it by setting
```

System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

before I did my HTTP calls. There seems to be a problem with Android keep closed connections in its connection pool and trying to reuse them. 
The status attribute must return the result of running these steps:

```
  1.>   If the state is UNSENT or OPENED, return 0.

  2.>  If the error flag is set, return 0.

  3.>  Return the HTTP status code.
```

We can dig deeper into the spec and find out just what those conditions for returning 0 mean. 
From http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#states:
http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/troubleshooting.html
From docuemntation http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-status-attribute means a request was cancelled before going anywhere.

Comment: Sorry but I can't test that anymore. Our setup has changed quite a lot in the meantime.